# how do I pass a string to a ruby ActiveRecord and baby_sequel query

Tags: ruby, activerecord, string-interpolation

I have the following query:

`Event.where.has { (status == 'active')}`

I want to be able to pass a string to the query such as `string = "(status == 'active')"` rather than writing it in the actual statement.

How could I do something like this?

I tried to use `String.interpolate {string}` within the `Event.where.has` statement, but it generated an error.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a bad idea to evaluate a `String` as Ruby code.

You could achieve something similar by using lambdas.

```
func = ->() { status == 'active' }
Event.where.has(&func)
```

But if you really want to use a `String`, you could use `eval`. Keep in mind this will leave you open to injection attacks and make your code more difficult to understand.

```
string = "(status == 'active')"
Event.where.has { eval(string) }
```

Comment: Yes, if you eval a String and the contents of the String can be populated by the user, they could craft a String of Ruby code to execute on your server.

Comment: Will the lambda protect me from that?

Comment: Yes, using the lambda way will prevent this.